# About TabActivity,ActivityGroup,and Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, tabactivity, activitygroup

I have a TabActivity,which host an ActivityGroup.the ActivityGroup started an activity,When I press the back button,which "onBackPressed" Method will be called?

Comment: what do you mean by which `onBackPressed`?

Comment: because TabActiviy,ActivityGroup,And the current activity all has "onBackPressed" method.I don't know which method will be invoked

Answer (score 0):

If you have not overriddedn on BackPressed the back press will result in going to the activity before the tabwidget. If you want to override this you need to do it in the individual activites under the tab.